# C++ Python closes my program

Tags: python, c++, direct3d

I am writing a small program with Direct3D and Python in C++.
I created my window and everything is working fine. But if I try to call "Py_Initialize();" my program closes.

(It closes with code 1)
What is the problem?

EDIT: Here are some parts of my code.

**MainIncludes.h**

```
#include "Windows.h"
#include <d3d9.h>
#pragma comment (lib, "d3d9.lib")

#include <d3dx9.h>
#pragma comment (lib, "d3dx9.lib")
```

**main_d3dwindow.cpp**

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
               HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
               LPSTR lpCmdLine,
               int nCmdShow)
{
HWND hWnd;
WNDCLASSEX wc;

ZeroMemory(&wc, sizeof(WNDCLASSEX));

wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
wc.hInstance = hInstance;
wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW;
wc.lpszClassName = L"WindowClass";

RegisterClassEx(&wc);

hWnd = CreateWindowEx(NULL,
                      L"WindowClass",
                      L"Program",
                      WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
                      300, 300,
                      800, 600,
                      NULL,
                      NULL,
                      hInstance,
                      NULL);

ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
mainWindow = hWnd;

initD3D(hWnd);
init_python();

MSG msg;

while(TRUE)
{
    while(PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    if(msg.message == WM_QUIT)
        break;

    render_frame();
}

cleanD3D();

return msg.wParam;
}
```

**main_python.cpp**

```
#include "Python.h"
void init_python() {
     Py_Initialize();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please *show* the code or it won't be possible for anyone to help you. (Preferably create a small reproducible example, removing parts of the code that don't relate to the problem)

Comment: Can you provide a code example? It's hard to say with just the function call.

Comment: what's the *exact* error message?

Comment: what's the definition headers, what are initD3D, render_frame, cleanD3D? More complete your files are complete, more likely somebody with experience would come up with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, Py_Initialize() simply initializes Python itself but not as
an interactive interpreter. At this point, Python is running but is waiting
for commands to be executed. Plus, you shouldn't forget to call Py_Finalize() to release the memory.

```
void pythonShell() {
   Py_Initialize();
   std::string pythonCommand = "execfile('python_script.py')"; // file or python command
   PyRun_SimpleString(pythonCommand.c_str());
   FILE* fp = stdin;
   char filename[] = "Embedded";
   PyRun_InteractiveLoop(fp, filename);
   Py_Finalize();
}
```

The PyRun_InteractiveLoop() function executes an interactive shell from your C++ code if you want it to.
I think that what's happening here, is that you just initialize Python, and that's it, it does not have anything to do as you don't pass it any script/command.

Hope this helps